# How to get the title of the foreground process/window

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I am developping a crossplatform desktop application using Electron, nodeJs and angular2.
My application needs to know, at all time, which  foreground process/window  is running on the computer. 
Do you have any idea on how to achieve such a task ?

Comment: Maybe the solution is different for each OS.  In this case, I  prefer to have a solution working on Linux computers first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to detect platform which runs Node app:

`os.platform()` - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_platform

Then you need to run platform specific command for getting process info with `child_process.exec()`.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It was really helpful.

Comment: Can you add any more detail as to how you use child_process.exec() to detect which window is in the foreground?

Answer (score 3):

To get metadata on active window you can use [sindresorhus/active-win](https://github.com/sindresorhus/active-win): it is multi platform (win, osx, linux) and very easy to implement